# AngularJS: How to parse JSON string to integer or float to display it in form number field

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, laravel

I am using AngularJS for my front-end and Laravel for the back-end. I am passing a variable to front-end screen called `orderItems` which contains the following data to my front-end.

```
[{
    "item_description": "CAD Machine ",
    "qty": "1",
    "unit_price": "4000.00"
}, {
    "item_description": "Lenovo laptop",
    "qty": "1",
    "unit_price": "3000.00"
}]
```

My front-end contains one text field and two number fields. Data is getting populated on text field and no data is showing up on number field.

Here is my code from the **view:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in order.items">
            <td>
                {{ Form::text("description[]",null, ['ng-model' => 'item.item_description', 'class' => 'input-small form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Item description', 'required']) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ Form::number("quantity[]", null, ['step' => 'any', 'ng-model' => 'item.qty', 'class' => 'input-mini form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Qty']) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ Form::number("cost[]", null, ['step' => 'any', 'ng-model' => 'item.unit_price', 'class' => 'input-mini form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unit Price', 'required']) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4><% item.qty * item.cost | currency %></h4>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <h5><a href ng-click="removeItem($index)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a></h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my **controller** where I assign `orderItems` to the scope element

```
app.controller('POEditFormController', function($scope) {
    $scope.order = {
        items: <?= $orderItems ?>
    };

    $scope.addItem = function() {
            var len = $scope.order.items.length;
            var prevItem = $scope.order.items[len - 1];
            if (prevItem.item_description == "" || prevItem.unit_price == "") {
                alert("Please enter the line details.");
            } else {
                $scope.order.items.push({
                    qty: 1,
                    item_description: '',
                    unit_price: ''
                });
            }
        },

        $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
            $scope.order.items.splice(index, 1);
        },

        $scope.total = function() {
            var total = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.order.items, function(item) {
                total += item.qty * item.unit_price;
            })

            return total;
        }
});
```

Because of my limited knowledge, I am not sure how to parse the `qty` and `unit_price` to float/integer.

Comment: In your json, the numbers should really be float/int instead of string? It would be best to change it at the server. Is that an option?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make changes at the server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wayne thanks for the suggestion, I managed to change the server response by setting up the accessors on the model class for qty and unit_price

```
public function getQtyAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['qty'] = (float)$value;
}

public function getUnitPriceAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['unit_price'] = (float)$value;
}
```

Here is the link to [Laravel's Eloquent Accessors & Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse them in this case.

In general, Javascript is interpreted, so in most browsers if you do the following:

```
"3.5"*"2"
```

It will work.
However, if for some reasons you need to force the parsing, you can use:

```
parseFloat
parseInt
```

In

```
total += parseInt(item.qty) * parseFloat(item.unit_price);
```

These are two functions which respectively parse the string and return the parsed value.

These two are the most reliable functions. There are others possibilities, such as:

```
+ before the number (such as +"3.5")
Integer.parseInt(myNumber)
```

But these are not recognized in every browser

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, how do you show value in form input type=number ?